# Inexpensive way to add time series intensity in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, plot, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I am trying to sum (and plot) a total from functions which change states at different times using Python's Pandas.DataFrame. For example:

Suppose we have 3 people whose states can be a) holding nothing, b) holding a 5 pound weight, and c) holding a 10 pound weight. Over time, these people pick weights up and put them down. I want to plot the total amount of weight being held. So, given:

My brute forece attempt:

```
import pandas as ps
import math
import numpy as np

person1=[3,0,10,10,10,10,10]
person2=[4,0,20,20,25,25,40]
person3=[5,0,5,5,15,15,40]
allPeopleDf=ps.DataFrame(np.array(zip(person1,person2,person3)).T)
allPeopleDf.columns=['count','start1', 'end1', 'start2', 'end2', 'start3','end3']
allPeopleDfNoCount=allPeopleDf[['start1', 'end1', 'start2', 'end2', 'start3','end3']]
uniqueTimes=sorted(ps.unique(allPeopleDfNoCount.values.ravel()))
possibleStates=[-1,0,1,2] #extra state 0 for initialization
stateData={}
comboStates={}
#initialize dict to add up all of the stateData
for time in uniqueTimes:
    comboStates[time]=0.0
allPeopleDf['track']=-1
allPeopleDf['status']=-1
numberState=len(possibleStates)

starti=-1
endi=0
startState=0
for i in range(3):
    starti=starti+2
    print starti
    endi=endi+2
    for time in uniqueTimes:
        def helper(row):
            start=row[starti]
            end=row[endi]
            track=row[7]
            if start <= time and time < end:
                return possibleStates[i+1]
            else:
                return possibleStates[0]
        def trackHelp(row):
            status=row[8]
            track=row[7]    
            if track<=status:
                return status
            else:
                return track
        def Multiplier(row):
            x=row[8]
            if x==0:
                return 0.0*row[0]
            if x==1:
                return 5.0*row[0]
            if x==2:
                return 10.0*row[0]
            if x==-1:#numeric place holder for non-contributing
                return 0.0*row[0]    
        allPeopleDf['status']=allPeopleDf.apply(helper,axis=1)
        allPeopleDf['track']=allPeopleDf.apply(trackHelp,axis=1)
        stateData[time]=allPeopleDf.apply(Multiplier,axis=1).sum()
    for k,v in stateData.iteritems():
        comboStates[k]=comboStates.get(k,0)+v
print allPeopleDf
print stateData
print comboStates
```

Plots of weight being held over time might look like the following:

[image]

And the sum of the intensities over time might look like the black line in the following:

[image]

with the black line defined with the Cartesian points: (0,0 lbs),(5,0 lbs),(5,5 lbs),(15,5 lbs),(15,10 lbs),(20,10 lbs),(20,15 lbs),(25,15 lbs),(25,20 lbs),(40,20 lbs). However, I'm flexible and don't necessarily need to define the combined intensity line as a set of Cartesian points. The unique times can be found with:
    print list(set(uniqueTimes).intersection(allNoCountT[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTaiV.jpg)].values.ravel())).sort()
,but I can't come up with a slick way of getting the corresponding intensity values.

I started out with a very ugly function to break apart each "person's" graph so that all people had start and stop times (albeit many stop and start times without state change) at the same time, and then I could add up all the "chunks" of time. This was cumbersome; there has to be a slick pandas way of handling this. If anyone can offer a suggestion or point me to another SO like that I might have missed, I'd appreciate the help!

In case my simplified example isn't clear, another might be plotting the intensity of sound coming from a piano: there are many notes being played for different durations with different intensities. I would like the sum of intensity coming from the piano over time. While my example is simplistic, I need a solution that is more on the scale of a piano song: thousands of discrete intensity levels per key, and many keys contributing over the course of a song.

***Edit--Implementation of mgab's provided solution:***

```
import pandas as ps
import math
import numpy as np

person1=['person1',3,0.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0]
person2=['person2',4,0,20,20,25,25,40]
person3=['person3',5,0,5,5,15,15,40]
allPeopleDf=ps.DataFrame(np.array(zip(person1,person2,person3)).T)
allPeopleDf.columns=['id','intensity','start1', 'end1', 'start2', 'end2', 'start3','end3']
allPeopleDf=ps.melt(allPeopleDf,id_vars=['intensity','id'])
allPeopleDf.columns=['intensity','id','timeid','time']
df=ps.DataFrame(allPeopleDf).drop('timeid',1)
df[df.id=='person1'].drop('id',1) #easier to visualize one id for check
df['increment']=df.groupby('id')['intensity'].transform( lambda x: x.sub(x.shift(), fill_value= 0 ))
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

***End Edit***

Comment: What are 'start1', 'end1', and so on? times? Do you really have just a few labelled times when the weights/note intensities may change or is it more like a continuum? I mean, does the 'start1' labels have a meaning for you or are just part of the simplification for the question? In my answer I assumed you could treat your data as _at second 23 person 2 changes its weight to 15_... but we can adapt it...

Comment: Also, what does the initial value for each list mean (the `3`,`4` and `5`)? I thought that the rest of values represented the weight being carried by that person at each time point, but I'm confused after seeing the output of `allPeopleDf.columns=['intensity','id','timeid','time'].` Try to explain how your **real** data is organized so we can adapt the code to it.

Comment: To continue the piano example: startx/endx refer to the start and end time a key plays with a certain intensity. start1/end1 could be the times that each key plays with intensity 0, start2/end2 could be the times that each key plays with intensity x etc.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with the 3,4,5--those are weights applied to the final result. For example, given the same intensity for notes A,B, and C, perhaps a person will hear C more easily, so I allowed for some weighting factors. I'll leave it in the example so that I don't cause more confusion by removing it, but feel free to ignore.

Comment: Then, if values for `person1` are `[3,0,10,10,10,10,10]`, what does it mean? Do you really need to organize your data like this? What is your real application case? Does it make sense to record only every time a key changes its intensity, at what time this happens and what the new intensity is? Too many questions... sorry but it is not clear to me how is your example data organized, and thus I cannot process it... :S

Comment: Thank you for your persistence. For person1 in my example, from time 0 to 10 the person is in state 1 (holding 0 pounds). The person does not change state after that--the person is in state2 (holding 5 pounds) from time 10 to 10, and in state 3 from time 10 to 10 (holding 10 pounds). And perhaps the label for person is strong, so they'll hold 3 times the weight for any given state. This is not a great way to represent the data--unfortunately, I don't have control over how it is represented.

Comment: _the person is in state2 (holding 5 pounds) from time 10 to 10, and in state 3 from time 10 to 10 (holding 10 pounds)_?? so is it in state 2 or state 3 at all?

Comment: answer edited. I think now it should be fine. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going for the piano keys example, lets assume you have three keys, with 30 levels of intensity.

I would try to keep the data in this format:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,'A',5],
                   [10,'B',7],
                   [13,'C',10],
                   [15,'A',15],
                   [20,'A',7],
                   [23,'C',0]], columns=["time", "key", "intensity"])

   time   key  intensity
0    10     A          5
1    10     B          7
2    13     C         10
3    15     A         15
4    20     A          7
5    23     C          0
```

where you record every change in intensity of any of the keys. From here you can already get the Cartesian coordinates for each individual key as `(time,intensity)` pairs

```
df[df.key=="A"].drop('key',1)

   time  intensity
0    10          5
3    15         15
4    20          7
```

Then, you can easily create a new column `increment` that will indicate the change in intensity that occurred for that key at that time point (`intensity` indicates just the new value of intensity)

```
df["increment"]=df.groupby("key")["intensity"].transform(
                             lambda x: x.sub(x.shift(), fill_value= 0 ))
df

   time key  intensity  increment
0    10   A          5          5
1    10   B          7          7
2    13   C         10         10
3    15   A         15         10
4    20   A          7         -8
5    23   C          0        -10
```

And then, using this new column, you can generate the `(time, total_intensity)` pairs to use as Cartesian coordinates

```
df.groupby("time").sum()["increment"].cumsum()

time
10      12
13      22
15      32
20      24
23      14
dtype: int64
```

### EDIT: applying the specific data presented in question

Assuming the data comes as a list of values, starting with the element id (person/piano key), then a factor multiplying the measured weight/intensities for this element, and then pairs of time values indicating the start and end of a series of known states (weight being carried/intensity being emitted). **Not sure if I got the data format right**. From your question:

```
data1=['person1',3,0.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0]
data2=['person2',4,0,20,20,25,25,40]
data3=['person3',5,0,5,5,15,15,40]
```

And if we know the weight/intensity of each one of the states, we can define:

```
known_states = [5, 10, 15]
DF_columns = ["time", "id", "intensity"]
```

Then, the easiest way I came up to load the data includes this function:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_data(data, states, columns):
    id = data[0]
    factor = data[1]
    reshaped_data = []
    for i in xrange(len(states)):
        j += 2+2*i
        if not data[j] == data[j+1]:
            reshaped_data.append([data[j], id, factor*states[i]])
            reshaped_data.append([data[j+1], id, -1*factor*states[i]])
    return pd.DataFrame(reshaped_data, columns=columns)
```

Notice that the `if not data[j] == data[j+1]:` avoids loading data to the dataframe when *start* and *end* times for a given state are equal (seems uninformative, and wouldn't appear in your plots anyway). But take it out if you still want these entries.

Then, you load the data:

```
df = read_data(data1, known_states, DF_columns)
df = df.append(read_data(data2, known_states, DF_columns), ignore_index=True)
df = df.append(read_data(data3, known_states, DF_columns), ignore_index=True)
# and so on...
```

And then you're right at the beginning of this answer (substituting 'key' by 'id' and the ids, of course)

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for! I'll check this, post my brute force solution for comparison, and award the bounty. Thank you.

Comment: I added an implementation of your answer above. I get an error on implimentation of the the transform function: ...unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'. I'm new to python, and am still digesting the df["increment"] line. Any thoughts on the source of this error?

Comment: I added a correction in the last line of code. I used meaningless column names like 'A', 'C' and so on for code testing and then I forgot to change 'C' to 'increment. Now it's corrected. This is not causing your error, however. I commented your question to try to clarify it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be what `.sum()` is for:

```
In [10]:

allPeopleDf.sum()
Out[10]:
aStart     0
aEnd      35
bStart    35
bEnd      50
cStart    50
cEnd      90
dtype: int32
```

Comment: I like the use of .sum(), thank you. In my example, to reproduce the black line, I would think that I would need the sum of intensity values for each of the time steps: 0,5,15,20,25,40. So, in my weight example, the black plot might be made with the following cartesian points:(0,0 lbs)(5,0 lbs)(5,5 lbs)(15,5 lbs)(15,10 lbs)(20,10 lbs)(20,15 lbs)(25,15 lbs)(25,20 lbs)(40,20 lbs). I'll edit the question to better reflect this.